# Optimizing array operations in Python with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm baffled. I just ported my code from Java to Python. Goods news is the Python alternative for the lib I'm using is much quicker. Bad part is that my custom processing code is much slower with the Python alternative I wrote :( I even removed some parts I deemed unnecessary, still much slower. The Java version took about half a second, Python takes 5-6.

```
rimg1 = imageio.imread('test1.png').astype(np.uint8)
rimg2 = imageio.imread('test2.png').astype(np.uint8)

sum_time = 0
for offset in range(-left, right):
    rdest = np.zeros((h, w, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

    if offset == 0:
        continue

    mult = np.uint8(1.0 / (offset * multiplier / frames))
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(0, w - backup, 1):
            slice_time = time.time()
            src = rimg2[y,x] // mult + 1
            sum_time += time.time() - slice_time

            pix = rimg1[y,x + backup]
```

w ~= 384 and h ~= 384
src ranges from 0 - 30 usually.
left to right is -5 to 5

How come sum_time takes about a third of my total time?

**Edit**

With the help of josephjscheidt I made some changes.

```
mult = np.uint8(1.0 / (offset * multiplier / frames))
multArray = np.floor_divide(rimg2, mult) + 1
for y in range(h):
    pixy = rimg1[y]
    multy = multArray[y]
    for x in range(0, w - backup, 1):
        src = multy[y]
        slice_time = time.time()
        pix = pixy[x + backup]
        sum_time += time.time() - slice_time
        ox = x
        for o in range(src):
            if ox < 0:
                break

            rdest[y,ox] = pix
            ox-=1
```

Using the numpy iterator for the srcArray cuts total time almost in half! The numpy operation itself seems to take negligible time.

Now most of the time taken is in rimg1 lookup

```
pix = rimg1[x + backup]
```

and the inner for loop (both taking 50% of time). Is it possible to handle this with numpy operations as well?

**Edit**

I would figure rewriting it could be of benefit, but somehow the following actually takes a little bit longer:

```
    for x in range(0, w - backup, 1):
        slice_time = time.time()
        lastox = max(x-multy[y], 0)
        rdest[y,lastox:x] = pixy[x + backup]
        sum_time += time.time() - slice_time
```

**Edit**

```
            slice_time = time.time()
            depth = multy[y]
            pix = pixy[x + backup]

            ox = x

            #for o in range(depth):
            #    if ox < 0:
            #        break;
            #
            #    rdesty[ox] = pix
            #    ox-=1

            # if I uncomment the above lines, and comment out the following two
            # it takes twice as long!
            lastox = max(x-multy[y], 0)
            rdesty[lastox:x] = pixy[x + backup]

            sum_time += time.time() - slice_time
```

The python interpreter is strange..

Time taken is now 2.5 seconds for sum_time. In comparison, Java does it in 60ms

Comment: `time.time()` is going to be slow compared to `//` and `+`.

Comment: What are `h` and `w` and why is `rdest` never used?

Comment: Is this `sum_time` integral to the calculation, or just part of your benchmaking?  For benchmarking the `timeit` module is more useful (many of us use the `ipython %timeit magic`).

Comment: I take into account that time.time() may take up some time. I run with and without, the problem lies with numpy. h and w are used for the ranges in the for loop. rdest is written to, see update.I will look at timeit, it's only for benchmarking indeed.

Comment: @RobotRock First, can you describe what you are trying to accomplish in the nested for-loops in your second code block? It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Second, if you want to do *profiling* (checking how long things take), have a look at [line-profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler).

Comment: @RolandSmith The point of the algorithm is to offset pixels using depth values from rimg2 [h,w]. rdest is the resulting image. rimg1 is color image, which is shape [h,w,3]. I have some more logic into place that flips the direction when offset < 0, but it all boils down to the above lines pretty much.

Comment: @RobotRock Offset as in add a value to a pixel or as in move a pixel to a different location? Or something else?

Comment: @RolandSmith Basically 3D reprojection. A lot of values of rdest are going to be overwritten a couple of times, but it is still the best way to do it.

Comment: @RobotRock In that case you could simply compare two numpy arrays using the standard `>` or `<`. That would result in an array of `bool`. You could then use that with `numpy.where` to choose which value to take.

Comment: @RolandSmith I don't think .where works here. I have to loop to the array from a specific direction; I can't tell with a bool which pixel is going to end up at what places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For loops are notoriously slow with numpy arrays, and you have a three-layer for loop here. The underlying concept with numpy arrays is to perform operations on the entire array at once, rather than trying to iterate over them.

Although I can't entirely interpret your code, because most of the variables are undefined in the code chunk you provided, I'm fairly confident you can refactor here and vectorize your commands to remove the loops. For instance, if you redefine offset as a one-dimensional array, then you can calculate all values of mult at once without having to invoke a for loop: mult will become a one-dimensional array holding the correct values.  We can avoid dividing by zero using the out argument (setting the default output to the offset array) and where argument (performing the calculation only where offset doesn't equal zero):

```
mult = np.uint8(np.divide(1.0, (offset * multiplier / frames),
                          out = offset, where = (offset != 0))
```

Then, to use the mult array on the rimg2 row by row, you can use a broadcasting trick (here, I'm assuming you want to add one to each element in rimg2):

```
src = np.floor_divide(rimg2, mult[:,None], out = rimg2, where = (mult != 0)) + 1
```

I found this article extremely helpful when learning how to effectively work with numpy arrays:

https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/

Since you are working with images, you may want to especially pay attention to the section on image feature extraction and stride_tricks. Anyway, I hope this helps you get started.

Comment: That took almost half of my run time! I didn't know numpy iterators were so much faster. Perhaps you know how to deal with my nested for loop as well, as that seems tricky to me. I've updated the question.

Comment: You have to break away from the for-loop structure. It looks like maybe you can subset an array to get the pixels you need? Something like rimg[ : , : w - backup]. Try to figure out what you are doing to each pixel, and perform the operation on the appropriate array of pixels instead.

Comment: I tried that for the most inner loop and it actually took longer. I ended up implementing a bridge with jpype and it's much quicker.